# why does my bot crash with an undefined error after one use?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've got this set of code for my discord bot that's supposed to work like via a say or a hug or a kiss command if you know what that is.

The problem is it works one time then it crashes due to display name being undefined?

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!);
});

client.on('message', message => { 
  let personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();
  message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' has shelled ' + personTagged.displayName + ' ' + doshellAction());
});

function doshellAction() {
    var rand = [
        'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690130408276230195/712567336971927582/ku-xlarge_2.gif',
        'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690127154742165504/712574767357493248/giphy_1.gif',
        'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690130408276230195/712586095908487168/SizzlingFrailItaliangreyhound-size_restricted.gif',
        'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690130408276230195/712586190418608149/NegligibleColorfulAfricanrockpython-size_restricted.gif',
        'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690130408276230195/712586220907003944/BruisedSparseButterfly-max-1mb.gif'

    ];
    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
}

client.login('removed for privacy');
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined"

Comment: Do you get that error even when mentioning a member?

Comment: yea. not sure why? :/

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for any sort of prefixes, so your code is being triggered by any message the bot sees, which don't always mention someone. What you can do to counter that is add a check before you run the code, to ensure the user actually intends to interact with your bot:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   if (!message.content.startsWith('shell')) return;
   let personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();
   message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' has shelled ' + personTagged.displayName + ' ' + doshellAction())
});
```

In the example above, we check if the message starts with `shell`, and return if it doesn't. To trigger your code, users would then post `shell @someone` to any channel the bot can see.

Comment: hey thank you very much and i apologize if im bothering but itried running this and it threw me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined" error  code

Comment: @colbycanterbury there was a typo in my code. Try again?